# How to insert an int i Razor when creating a tag without causing a space

Tags: c#, razor

How can I build up a string with an index so that Razor doesn't require me to use space? This works but the generated markup has spaces around the *@i* expression.

```
@for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{ <img src="Images/Image @i .png" />}
```

This doesn't work because semicolon is missing.

```
@for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{ <img src="Images/Image@{i}.png" />}
```

This fails because the increment (one of the allowed operations) doesn't produce a value.

```
@for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{ <img src="Images/Image @{i++;}.png" />}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{ <img src="Images/Image@(i).png" />}
```

Alternatively:

```
@for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{ 
    string source = "Images/Image" + i + ".png";
    <img src="@source" />
}
```

Comment: First time ever I see *@()* instead of *@{}*... It works, as answer accepted and for +1, I'd like to see you r comment on that.